# Problem with getting RSS because of authentication

Tags: rss, authentication

Im am trying to get the rss feed from a wordpress website that someone else has built. But I get stuck in authentication problems, and i am not able to find the right solution.

When I put http://dummyname.nl/feed in SoapUI I get the login page as a response and not the RSS feed. (off course dummyname is not the real url).

Someone said I should install and activate this plugin https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth

I did, but nothing changes.

What configuration settings I need to change to set this open for getting the feed out of this website

Mvg, Rogier

Comment: /feed isn't protected by default, so something you've installed must be adding authentication to it. Can you try temporarily switching themes or disabling plugins to see if that fixes it, to work out what's causing this?

Comment: Or it could also be something in .htaccess or equivalent I suppose, e.g. set to return 401 from there, but I don't know if that would trigger WordPress's authentication

Comment: And I'd guess that plugin you linked is for REST API authentication and wouldn't affect /feed.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I disabled all the plugins one by one and it was the members plugin that blocked it. So that was the right answer. Thanks.  It was the members plugin from https://memberpress.com/ . So I must investigate now if this is really needed and/or I can create a role to reach my goal.

Comment: Great! I suspect it does that in case any members-only content gets leaked out in the feed, so you might need to see if you can configure memberpress to just filter the feed when unauthenticated rather than disabling it completely.